# Avoid code duplication with a runtime type switch (and templated function)

Tags: c++

I have some point clouds and some spatial index classes such as `QuadTree`, `Octree`, `Partion` to make fast queries in the point clouds. Depending on the point cloud structure it may be suitable to use a given spatial index type or another.

All the spatial index classes have the same public members: a constructor, `insert`, `lookup` and `knn`. Obviously the implementations are different and private members are different.

```
class SpatialIndexType {
  public:
    SpatialIndexType(const std::vector<Point>&);
    bool insert(const Point&);
    template<typename T> void lookup(T& shape, std::vector<Point>&);
    void knn(const Point&, const unsigned int, std::vector<Point>&);
}
```

I use my classes typically this way (pseudo code)

```
// Build a spatial index
SpatialIndexType index(point_cloud);

// Make successive queries of points in a shape
// (here a disc)
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
  Disc disc(x[i], y[i], radius);
  std::vector<Point> pts;
  index.lookup(disc, pts);

  // Do something with pts which might be many lines of code
}
```

Now let assume that I know that the structure of my `point_cloud` requires to use an Octree instead of a Quadtree **at runtime**. I could create a switch function (pseudo code)

```
do_something(point_cloud, type) {
  switch(type) {
    case 1: do_something_with_quadtree(point_cloud)
    case 2: do_something_with_octree(point_cloud)
    case 3: do_something_with_partition(point_cloud)
  }
}
```

And all my `do_something_with_*` functions will be **strictly** identical. They will differ by a single word: the `SpatialIndexType` that can be either `QuadTree`, `Octree`, `Partition` or potentially something else.

I'm pretty sure it exists a clever way to avoid such silly code duplication. I tried to inherit from a virtual class `SpatialIndex` but I get stuck with the templated `lookup` member that cannot be defined `virtual`.

Comment: I started writing an answer based on `std::variant` but realized halfway through that the particular case in your question doesn't need it and is better covered by Jarod's answer. But as soon as you want to use a runtime-variable `SpatialIndexType` as a member in a (non-templated) class, you might need to use a different tool: https://godbolt.org/z/hDPPbQ

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Just added selection by `variant` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might template your function

```
template <typename SpatialIndexType>
void do_something(const std::vector<Point>& point_cloud)
{
    // Build a spatial index
    SpatialIndexType index(point_cloud);

    // Make successive queries of points in a shape
    // (here a disc)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
      Disc disc(x[i], y[i], radius);
      std::vector<Point> pts;
      index.lookup(disc, pts);

      // Do something with pts which might be many lines of code
    }
}
```

and your runtime dispatcher:

```
void do_something(const std::vector<Point>& point_cloud, int type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 1: do_something_with<Quadtree>(point_cloud);
        case 2: do_something_with<Octree>(point_cloud);
        case 3: do_something_with<Partition>(point_cloud);
    }
}
```

If you have to dispatch several times, you might use `std::variant` to factorize the dispatching:

```
template <typename> struct Tag{};

using SpatialIndexTypeVariant = std::variant<Tag<QuadTree>, Tag<Octree>, Tag<PArtition>>;

SpatialIndexTypeVariant RuntimeType(int type)
{
    switch (type) {
        case 1: return Tag<Quadtree>();
        case 2: return Tag<Octree>();
        case 3: return Tag<Partition>();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Unknown type");
}
```

and then (C++20):

```
std::visit([&]<typename T>(Tag<T>){ do_something_with<T>(point_cloud); }, RuntimeType(type));
```

For C++17, you might change signature of generic function to:

```
template <typename SpatialIndexType>
void do_something(Tag<SpatialIndexType>, const std::vector<Point>& point_cloud);
```

and use regular generic lambda.

```
std::visit([&](auto tag){ do_something_with(tag, point_cloud); }, RuntimeType(type));
```

Comment: Of course, this is actually obvious. It does not remove the ugly switch but is pretty elegant anyway.

Comment: @JRR: Added version to have `switch` only once.

Comment: @Jarod42 Why the tag approach? Why not a variant of the types themselves?

Comment: Thanks, `std::variant` is completely new for me but seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Now I have a keyword to put in a search engine.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Might depend of the function, suppose that function generate `SpatialIndexType` inside the function (we currently might change input, but, function might create several `SpatialIndexType`, or change inputs point, which disallow your option...)